# Why do I need to use assertThat() and and() in Rest-Assured?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, assert, rest-assured, assertion

My question is, what is the difference if I use .assertThat() and .and() methods to validate the response with rest-assured?

For example:

```java
then().assertThat().statusCode(200).and().contentType(ContentType.JSON)
```

and

```java
then().statusCode(200).contentType(ContentType.JSON)
```

Both cases will fail if response code is not 200 or content type is XML, and it will return the same response, regardless whether you're using assertThat() and and() or not:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected status code <404> but was <200>.
```

Is that just a syntactic sugar?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both are equivalent. assertThat()/and() are indeed syntactic sugars that aid in readability

From javadocs:

**T and()**

Syntactic sugar, e.g.

```
get("/something").then().assertThat().body(containsString("OK")).and().body(containsString("something else"));
```

is that same as:

```
get("/something").then().assertThat().body(containsString("OK")).body(containsString("something else"));
```

**T assertThat()**

Syntactic sugar, e.g.

```
get("/something").then().assertThat().body(containsString("OK")).and().body(containsString("something else"));
```

is that same as:

```
 get("/something").then().body(containsString("OK")).body(containsString("something else"));
```

**T using()**

Syntactic sugar, e.g.

```
get("/something").then().using().defaultParser(JSON).assertThat().body(containsString("OK")).and().body(containsString("something else"));
```

is that same as:

```
get("/something").then().defaultParser(JSON).body(containsString("OK")).body(containsString("something else"));
```

Javadocs: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.jayway.restassured/rest-assured/latest/com/jayway/restassured/response/ValidatableResponseOptions.html